# How to convert anonymous type to Entity of Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have the following query

```
            var db = new Entities();
            IQueryable<Tbl_RSCRegularSupply> qrySupp = (from cont in db.Tbl_RSC
                                                        where cont.ID == contractID
                                                        let RegSupp = new
                                                       {
                                                           RegSupply = from R in cont.Tbl_RSCSupplyPlan
                                                                       select R.Tbl_RSCRegularSupply
                                                       }

                                                        select (Tbl_RSCRegularSupply)RegSupp.RegSupply);


            return qrySupp.AsParallel().ToList();
```

But After executing this creating the following Exception.

Unable to cast the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1' to type 'Tbl_RSCRegularSupply'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Is it some good way to get the `List<Tbl_RSCRegularSupply>` from above query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `RegSupp.RegSupply` is an `IEnumerable<EntitySet<Tbl_RSCRegularSupply>>`, so it cannot be cast to `Tbl_RSCRegularSupply`. In other words, you have a list of lists, not a list of items.

I don't know your specifications, but you could do

```
} ... select RegSupp.RegSupply.Selectmany(r => r));
```

which flattens the result in one list.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.I agree with you that it return something like that IEnumerable<EntitySet<Tbl_RSCRegularSupply>> but how it possible to get List<Tbl_RSCRegularSupply>